# jEdit Hypersearch like results in VIM?

Tags: search, vim, editor, jedit

In jEdit, you can do what is called a hyper search, which lists all of the search results in one pane, and allows you to click on them to jump to that place in the text.

Does vim have a similar functionality, using a plugin or otherwise?

Comment: Do you mean something similar to [Taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/), but listing the current search pattern's results by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the quickfix list or the location list.

To search for `foo` in the current buffer and display a list of all the occurrences, do:

```
:vim foo % | copen  <-- use the quickfix list
:lvim foo % | lopen <-- use the location list
```

To search for `foo` in the current buffer's directory and display a list of all the occurrences, do:

```
:vim foo .* | copen
```

See `:h quickfix`.